# Why FBSDK Share Dialog does not work with image attachment?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share

I want to share image on Facebook, for this I do:

```
let photo: FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = croppedImage
photo.userGenerated = true
photo.caption = "Add Your caption"

let content: FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [photo]

FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)
```

but it does not show me ShareViewController. But when I'm trying this code:

```
let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://")
content.contentTitle = "App Testing"
content.contentDescription = "I'm working over the app!"
```

How can I fix the first snippet?

Comment: Do you have the Facebook app installed? `FBSDKSharePhoto` requires the app. From [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#model): "People need the native Facebook for iOS app installed, version 7.0 or higher"

Comment: @ama1111 of course! `FBSDKShareLinkContent` works, but `FBSDKSharePhotoContent` - not

Comment: To get more info you could implement the `FBSDKSharingDelegate`, pass to `showFromViewController` and see what it reports for `didFailWithError`.

Comment: @ama1111 can you please help me with example?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2016/01/facebook-sdk-and-swift-post-message.html) of implementing the `FBSDKSharingDelegate`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you figured out how to fix it?

Comment: Did you receive alerts from [Facebook developer](http://developers.facebook.com) that you are in violation of Section 2.3 of the Facebook Platform Policies? Facebook may placed a restriction on photos published for it.

Comment: hey, did you find a work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but just in case anyone faces the same issue:

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#photos), You need the native Facebook app to be installed in order to use `FBSDKSharePhotoContent` and you cannot use `FBSDKShareDialog` in that case.

A close workaround to achieve *almost* the same result is using `FBSDKShareDialog` (which only supports `FBSDKShareLinkContent`) as follows:

```
let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.imageURL = URL(string: "www.example.com/my_image.jpg")
content.contentURL = URL(string: "www.example.com/target_url")
content.contentTitle = "My Title"
content.contentDescription = "My Description"

let dialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.delegate = self      // make sure to conform to FBSDKSharingDelegate protocol
dialog.shareContent = content
if !dialog.canShow() {
    // fallback to non-native mode
    dialog.mode = .feedBrowser
}
dialog.show()
```

You can find the protocol's methods [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKSharingDelegate/).

Comment: Careful using this approach; the mentioned content attributes are marked in the SDK as deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It only works when Facebook app is installed. Also, specify `mode = .native` explicitly.

```
let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: image, userGenerated: true)
    content.photos = [photo].flatMap({ $0 })

    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.fromViewController = viewController
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.delegate = self
    dialog.mode = .native

    dialog.show()
```

If not, it will use `SLComposeViewController`, and you will get error

```
SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType got serviceType com.apple.social.facebook isAvailable 0
```

Good practice is to debug on `FBSDKShareDialog.m` to see if things don't work for you

```
- (BOOL)show
{
  BOOL didShow = NO;
  NSError *error = nil;

  if ([self _validateWithError:&error]) {
    switch (self.mode) {
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic:{
        didShow = [self _showAutomatic:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser:{
        didShow = [self _showBrowser:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser:{
        didShow = [self _showFeedBrowser:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb:{
        didShow = [self _showFeedWeb:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeNative:{
        didShow = [self _showNativeWithCanShowError:&error validationError:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet:{
        didShow = [self _showShareSheetWithCanShowError:&error validationError:&error];
        break;
      }
      case FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb:{
        didShow = [self _showWeb:&error];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!didShow) {
    [self _invokeDelegateDidFailWithError:error];
  } else {
    [self _logDialogShow];
    [FBSDKInternalUtility registerTransientObject:self];
  }
  return didShow;
}
```

Lesson learned:

- Be aware of FB changes.
- Check for change log every morning
- Things that work today may not work tomorrow